# How to export HTML file inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to export a webpage loaded inside an iFrame. But I want to have action from an outer iFrame.

Here's my code to clarify things:

```
<html>
    <body>
        some contents here....
        <div id="main">
            <iframe id="myiframe" src="template/index.html"></iframe>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="downloadLink">Export</a>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
                    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

                    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
                    link.click(); 
                }
                var fileName =  'newlstter.html';
                $('#downloadLink').click(function(){
                    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the `export` button the HTML file is exported and it will include the iFrame. But if I use these codes inside the inner HTML file it will export.
But I need to export that current HTML page from the outter site. Exactly like my code above. But I just want to export only the inner HTML.

Can any one give me some suggestion for this?
Note: Please I need jQuery or JS code, not PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi,
I am creating website builder. so I change everything inside that iFrame HTML file, finally I want to export that designed html file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an AJAX; the following fiddle returns just the HTML that you need: https://jsfiddle.net/yLL48one/2/

```
$.get( "/yLL48one/1/", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
 
I am creating website builder. so I change everything inside that iFrame HTML file, finally I want to export that designed html file. but in this case it will may download original file without designed things